# GitHub organisation overview tab: how to display list of repositories

Tags: github

It's kind of a weird one - I have several organisations under my GitHub account and some, under the Overview tab display the list of repositories, wheres others a list of different options under the heading `We think you’re gonna like it here.`. I don't think I've done anything different when setting each organisation, but does anyone know how to replace the

[image]

with list of repositories like under this organisation?

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yeah, there is a button on the right to hide that:

[image: Github UI]

Comment: Thanks very much Semyon - must've missed that.

Comment: most effective answer in my last month thx

Comment: This is an annoying feature. GitHub should remove that if all tasks are completed or in a time range.

Comment: Wow that link is so hidden. This is such an annoying "feature".

Comment: Came here a second time with the same problem ....  Found my own comment...

Comment: This is a terrible UX.